# Windows application automation using QAF

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, qaf

I'm looking support for automate windows application like notepad using Qmetry automation framework with BDD steps. is there any link or solution to implement. I tried with Appium driver but didn't work.

Step1: open Notepad
Step2: enter "Some text"[enter link description here][1]

Success log:
Windows Application Driver listening for requests at: http://127.0.0.1:4723/
Press ENTER to exit.

==========================================
POST /session HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 258
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/16.0.2)

{"capabilities":[{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe","platformName":"Windows"}},{"requiredCapabilities":{}}],"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe","platformName":"Windows"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 141
Content-Type: application/json

==========================================
GET /session/3E4610D7-9EBB-4998-921B-94220578D3F1 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/16.0.2)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 90
Content-Type: application/json

{"status":0,"value":{"app":"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe","platformName":"Windows"}}

---

Failure log:

Windows Application Driver listening for requests at: http://127.0.0.1:4723/
Press ENTER to exit.

==========================================
POST /wd/hub/session HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 641
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:4723
User-Agent: selenium/3.141.59 (java windows)
X-Idempotency-Key: 202d0858-641b-4263-88b9-4b5b1ed0ecc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provided what you tried and what is the error you are getting.

In order to automate windows native application you need to use appium windows driver. Windows driver is appium implementation so you can use it like android or ios appium driver.

You can refer

- [How to run native app on appium](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/how_to_run_on_native_app_on_appium.html)
- Driver specific [documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/#the-windows-driver) for set up and other driver specific requirements
- Sample working [configuration](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/issues/227#issuecomment-595917242).

**EDIT**: Below sample works fine:

**Properties** for [setting capabilities](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/setting_driver_capabilities.html)

```
remote.port=4723
driver.name= appiumDriver

appium.additional.capabilities={"app":"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe","driverClass":"io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver"}
#appium.capabilities.driverClass=io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver
#appium.capabilities.app=C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe
```

It worked well as normal web driver test without issue:

```
import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.CommonStep.sendKeys;
import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.StringMatcher.exact;
import static com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.ElementFactory.$;

...

    @Test
    public void testCanEditInNotpad(){
        getDriver().verifyTitle(exact("Untitled - Notepad"));
        getDriver().findElementByClassName("Edit").sendKeys("it worked!...")
        $("className=Edit").sendKeys(" This also worked!...");
        sendKeys(" Common Step worked as well!...", "className=Edit");
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to automate windows application like notepad, calculator using WinAppDriver in QAF and java bdd approach. My property file contains below properties.

remote.server=127.0.0.1
remote.port=4723
driver.name=appiumDriver
appium.additional.capabilities={'platformName':'Windows','deviceName':'WindowsPC','automationName':'Appium','app':'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe','driverClass':'io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver'

Comment: continue from above comment.

Issue: Notepad is not getting initialized by default. if I run below approach then its working as expected.

DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities1.setCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");  
NotepadSession = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities1);
  
NotepadSession.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Assert.assertEquals("Untitled - Notepad", NotepadSession.getTitle());        
NotepadSession.findElementByClassName("Edit").sendKeys("Some text");

Comment: easiest way is print capabilities that you are passing to  `WindowsDriver` and match with what you are setting in property. If you refer https://github.com/appium/appium-windows-driver you will get idea about supported capabilities and possible value. Try just `appium.additional.capabilities={'app':'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe','driverClass':'io.appium.java_client.windows.WindowsDriver'}`. if required you can try adding 'platformName':'Windows' and 'automationName': 'windows'

Comment: Furthermore when providing path either use `/` or \\ instead of  \ for instance, `C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe` or `C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe`

Comment: Tahnk you for your respose!

Comment: Hi, in below code, driver.findElement(id).senkeys("") is working fine. But common step of sendKeys("some text", "EDIT") is not working. could you please help us on this. mostly we are using common steps in our app.
 WindowsDriver driver = (WindowsDriver) new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver().getUnderLayingDriver();
capabilities1.setCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
driver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities1);
driver.findElementByClassName("Edit").sendKeys("Some text"); //its working
sendKeys("some text", "EDIT"); //Its not working

Comment: QAF common steps of sendkey, click etc... was not working.

Comment: refer updated answer. it works without any issue